# parentFormContext attribute in Primary Control is supported?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

There is one scenario in which the Entity data is shown in Subgrid which is inside the Quick View form.

On click of Custom New button, there is a requirement to populate the Parent record in lookup of Quick create on which this quick view is present.

So, on click of custom new button I am passing the parameters to quick create form in which the parent record reference is set on lookup field on quick create form.

I am using formContext.parentFormContext.data.entity.getEntityReference() to get the parent record reference. But I was not able to find any documentation regarding parentFormContext. Is it supported code or unsupported. Can anybody help me with that.

**Code**

[image]

**Attributes in Primary Control**

[image]

Comment: I think your `var projectRecord= formContext.parentFormContext.data.entity.getEntityReference()` you are trying to get lookup field. why not get it as `formContext.getAttribute(arg).getValue()`

Comment: @AnkUser I tried using formContext.getAttribute(agr).getValue() but the problem it is giving the context of current entity (child entity), but I need context of parent entity which is present in parentFormContext.

Comment: could you make something clear, what is your child entity and which is your parent?.
Also on your child entity do you not have a lookup field of parent entity (record). For example on contact (child) you should most of the time have field Account (Parent).

Comment: @Innocent Can you share the detail about `primaryControl`, is it a Subgrid ribbon? Is this Subgrid in a quick create form?